Cannot update a component (app) while rendering a different component ()
i'm designing a e commerce, when comes the part to delete a item from the cart, i have this issue passing values from my return to my delete item from localStorage function
Specifically this error: Cart.jsx:24 Warning: Cannot update a component (App) while rendering a different component (Cart). To locate the bad setState() call inside Cart, follow the stack trace as described in
 I've been tryied to put my usestate Set method inside a useeffect with [], but doesnt works
 well, here you have my code:

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Footer from "./Footer";

function Cart({ cart, setCart }) {
  const newCart = cart.flatMap((c) => c);
  const replaced = newCart.map(e => e.price.replaceAll('.', ''));
  let sum = 0

  replaced.forEach((price) => {
    sum += price * 1;
  });

  let finalSum = sum.toLocaleString()
//function to recharge page when empty all the localStorage
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    localStorage.clear();
    window.location.reload();
  }
//function to delete my product
  function deleteProd(id){
    const updCart = newCart.filter(e => e.id  !==id)
    setCart(updCart) //HERE IS THE ERROR
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(updCart))
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <h1>Carrito de Compras</h1>
      <div className="cartWrapper">
      {newCart.map((c) => (
        <div className="cartProd">
          <img src={c.img} alt="" />
          <h1>{c.prod}</h1>
          <h2>precio: ${c.price}</h2>
          <Link to={`/products/${c.id}`}>Ver producto</Link>
          <button onClick={deleteProd(c.id)}>Eliminar</button> //HERE I PASS THE PRODUCT ID TO MY FUNCTION
        </div>
      ))}
      <div className="right-bar">
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Vaciar Carrito</button>
        <h1>Total: ${finalSum}</h1>
      </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default Cart;


 Any respose will be received!!! thanks

Do not invoke the handler instead just pass it as such. @user28234598 has answered it.

Issue in code is in this line :
- <button onClick={deleteProd(c.id)}>Eliminar</button>

So whenever the cart component is getting rendered this function is directly getting executed which updates the cart state variable in parent component while rendering the Cart child component which is not allowed in react as updating the state variable while component is rendering which can cause unexpected results.
It is like you're writing something and suddenly your friend grabs your pen and starts updating the list which is not good.
Here's the solution for your issue.
Code with issue :

<button onClick={deleteProd(c.id)}>Eliminar</button> // Wrong function definition

Corrected code :

<button onClick={() => deleteProd(c.id)}>Eliminar</button> // Corrected code


Thanks!!! it worked, but I still have the question of knowing technically what the difference is between my code and the solution.

Hello buddy, Main issue with your code is that one line only where you have defined the deleteProd function. You're directly calling the function when rendering the cart component and as the function will have the id it will delete that record from the cart and trying to update the Cart State and it is getting updated in parent component which is giving that error. Now do you get me?
Try to create another Cart State variable with cart prop and then run your code it will.
Let me know if you still have any questions!
